# Implementing hierarchical clustering in Python using Levenshtein distance

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, levenshtein-distance, hierarchical

Following up on my previous question, I have implemented a clustering algorithm for a huge number of strings using Python & Levenshtein distance..But it is taking a very long time to complete clustering. Any suggestions please?

<>
iterate thro the list in a for loop
    for each item in list
        run through the list again, to find similarity percentage
        if similarity > threshold, move to cluster
    end for loop

Comment: Rewrite the hot parts in Cython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use a profiler to see where most of the time is spent. I suspect it's in the actual Levenshtein calculation, but it's good to be sure. *Iff it is:*

1. Implement the Levenshtein function with Cython. This will give you a massive speed-up already.
2. Calculate the pairs in multiple threads. E.g. If you have 1000 strings, you have 1000000 pairs, so you can have each of 8 threads do 125000 of the pairs.

Comment: thanks a lot.. let me check on this..

Comment: yes Levenshtein function is taking 90% of the time..